# How to create Microsoft GraphServiceClient in ASP.NET Core Web Api 6

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web Api 6 project generated by VS 2022, with MicrosoftIdentity authentication.
The required identifiers for logging in to AzureAd were filled in, AzureAD:ClientSecret was also saved in secrets.json.

It looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
             .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
             .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var scopeRequiredByApi = app.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"] ?? "";
```

```
{
   "AzureAd": {
     "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
     "Domain": "xxxxxxxxx",
     "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
     "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
     "Scopes": "access_as_user",
     "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal.",
     "ClientCertificates": []
   },
   "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Information",
       "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
     }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*",
   "MicrosoftGraph": {
     "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
     "Scopes": "user.read"
   }
}
```

Identifiers have been replaced with the text xxxxx.

I need to call MicrosoftGraph services, for example api for 'Get User'.

The Microsoft documentation lists this code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"]
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

The above configuration of the ASP.NET Web Api project contains all the identifiers required for authorization.

How to create an **authProvider** variable using the configured identifiers in the above context?

Well thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
```

adds the support for `GraphServiceClient` via dependency injection

In your controller: add `GraphServiceClient` parameter into the constructor and dependency injection will resolve the instance of `GraphServiceClient` with configured `authProvider`.

```
public class YourController
{
    private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    public YourController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I use "minimal api", so this should work too:

```
app.MapGet("/getuser", (Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient client) =>
{
    return (new MsTeamsMe().Run(client));
});
```

Unfortunately, the GraphServiceClient client configured in this way does not work properly. So it seems to me that it is safer - due to the significant complexity of authorization - to generate a functional GraphServiceClient instance manually:

```
    GraphServiceClient CreateClient()
    {

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = TeamsConstants.TenantId;

        // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(TeamsConstants.ClientId)
         .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
                        .WithClientSecret(TeamsConstants.ClientSecretValue)
                        .Build();

        // Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
        // which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
        // and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 

        return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {

            // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
                     .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                     .ExecuteAsync();

            // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                               new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        })
                       );
    }
```